# Automate the process of sending Postman Requests and save the responses in a file

Tags: rest, postman

I want to automate the process of sending get requests to an API and save the responses in a JSON file. I have researched a lot online and haven't found anything. I have created a collection and run it, but how do I automate it.

Comment: have you tried newman?

Comment: @Ray did it using newman and batch files. Thanks though. :)

Comment: @Ray is there anyway to download a json file with the actual response for get requests using newman??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have your tests collection built in Postman, you shall run it with newman (see useful options [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options), this link helped me a lot !).

If your collection can be run with Postman runner, it should work perfectly. I haven't tried to generate reports in JSON but it works fine for HTML and JUnit style reports ... and you can set a specific reporting parameter to have results set in a JSON file.